# Access Denied when Sellers add new product

Tags: 7, commerce

We created a store with Drupal 7 Commerce. Because we wanted to let specific users create new products on our store, a user role Seller was also created with the following permissions:

- Create, edit, delete **own** product display
- Create, edit, delete **own** products

We have also created a block with views that allows those users to access their own product listing and edit the products with the following settings in views:

- Contextual filters: (Node referencing products from field_product) Content: Author uid
- Relationships: Commerce Product: Referencing Content

A link to Add new product has also been created in that block, although I'm not sure this is the safest way to do it: `/admin/commerce/products/add/product`

We also use the following modules to make life easier:

- Auto product display
- Commerce AutoSKU
- Automatic Entity Labels

Everything works as should. When a Seller wants to add a new product, the add product form is shown in the front end (not admin overlay). But once the ADD PRODUCT button is clicked, it shows Access denied page - probably because it wants to redirect to the admin products list.

**Is there a way to redirect those users to their own listing or any other page on our website once they add a product, so they don't get that error?**

Comment: `/admin/commerce/products/add/product` since you added the admin access , they will definitely get a 'access denied' you must create a access by there login interface. like `/user/commerce/products/add/product` instead of using admin.

Comment: I have been trying to do that with no luck. Can you give me more specific instructions?